# Convert floating point and integer literals to fixed point literals using regex

Tags: python, regex, perl

I have this text

```
123.56013414
12
14.5
```

Is it possible to convert it to

```
123.560
12.000
14.500
```

using regex?

Comment: This is a job for `sprintf`, not regular expressions.

Comment: Why using a regex? It is a totally unreliable solution

Comment: Is this a Perl or a Python question? It is tagged as both.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_ = sprintf "%.3f", $_;
```

(A regular expression defines a set of strings. It doesn't perform changes. As such, I ignored the requirement to use do this using a regex pattern.)